# Force download of multiple files stopped working

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that triggers multiple files download. Unfortunately, for some reasons it stopped working (all browsers). It only downloads the last file for the last id.

```
// generate <a> tag for each id and trigger click event
ids.forEach(function(id) {
   var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/api/v1/files/' + id
   var anchor = angular.element('<a download></a>');
   anchor.attr({href: url, target: '_self'});
   anchor[0].click();
});
```

Any idea what causes this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of my problem. I changed target attribute of **a** tag to `_blank`, and I allowed **Popups** permissions. Here are the changes.

```
anchor.attr({href: url, target: '_blank'});
```

[image]